# Trying to send correctly formed object to view

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, model-view-controller

I am working on a class/homework project and I am trying to render a form that displays an order's details with each product title displayed on an individual line. Here is my model, controller, and view (respectively):

```
public class Order
  {
    [Key]
    public int OrderId {get;set;}

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    public DateTime DateCreated {get;set;}

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime? DateCompleted {get;set;}

    [Required]
    public string UserId {get; set;}

    [Required]
    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

    public int? PaymentTypeId {get;set;}
    public PaymentType PaymentType {get;set;}

    public virtual ICollection<OrderProduct> OrderProducts { get; set; }

    }
}


// GET: Orders/Details/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var order = await _context.Order
                .Include(o => o.OrderProducts)
                    .ThenInclude(op => op.Product)
                .Where(o => o.OrderId == id).ToListAsync();

            if (order == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(order);
        }

<dl class="row">
        <dt class="col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DateCreated)
        </dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.DateCreated)
        </dd>
        <dt class="col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.OrderProducts)
        </dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-10">
            @foreach (var product in Model.OrderProducts)
            {
                <div>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(Model => product.Product.Title)
                </div>
            }
        </dd>
    </dl>
```

I am currently receiving the error message:

"InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Bangazon.Models.Order]', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'Bangazon.Models.Order'."

My initial thought was that the order's ICollection of OrderProducts needed to be a List, but that didn't change the error at all. So, now I'm at a loss.

Thank you all for your consideration and patience. I am still very new to developing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var order = await _context.Order
                .Include(o => o.OrderProducts)
                    .ThenInclude(op => op.Product)
                .Where(o => o.OrderId == id).ToListAsync();
```

This will give you list of orders. But your view expect order.

```
var order = await _context.Order
                .Include(o => o.OrderProducts)
                    .ThenInclude(op => op.Product)
                .Where(o => o.OrderId == id).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

FirstOrDefault will give you first item in your where. But you better use SingleOrDefault().

Comment: The change you suggest now causes a build error that 'Order' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter'... can you guide as to how I rectify this? Thank you.

Comment: use FirstOrDefaultAsync

Comment: I was not familiar with that method. This is exactly what I needed. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Your model requires a class but the return type of your query is List. If model is required to be list put the model in List then create a loop for the model.

```
@model List<Order>

for (var i = 0; i <= Model.Count() - 1; i++){
    <dl class="row">
        <dt class="col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => Model[i].DateCreated)
        </dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(m => Model[i].DateCreated)
        </dd>
        <dt class="col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => Model[i].OrderProducts)
        </dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-10">
            @foreach (var product in Model[i].OrderProducts)
            {
                <div>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(Model => product.Product.Title)
                </div>
            }
        </dd>
    </dl>
}
```

or if you only want one Model not the list of model that follows the condition, follow @cdev suggestion